# Load All Phone Images to GridView with Thread in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, image, load

i have a problem with Thread in Android . i have a gridview with CheckBox and i want Load all Images Gallery to this Grid . but i want load this Thread. but when i click Load images program Closed. This is my Code . please See and give me best solution . Thanks

Add_Image.Java :

```
public class add_images extends Activity implements Runnable {

    private int count;
    private Bitmap[] thumbnails;
    private boolean[] thumbnailsselection;
    private String[] arrPath;
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    private String selectImages="";
    private final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_images);
        pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pd.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        pd.setIndeterminate(false);
        pd.setCancelable(true);
        pd.show();
        Thread t = new Thread(add_images.this);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        GetList();
    }

    private void GetList() {
        try {   

            final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
            final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
            Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,
                    null, null, orderBy);
            final int image_column_index = imagecursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
            this.count = imagecursor.getCount();
            this.thumbnails = new Bitmap[this.count];
            this.arrPath = new String[this.count];
            this.thumbnailsselection = new boolean[this.count];
            for (int i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
                imagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
                final   int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
                final   int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                thumbnails[i] = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                        getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), id,
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
                arrPath[i] = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);
                pd.setProgress(i);
            }
            GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.Add_Select_PhoneImageGrid);
            imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();
            imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
            imagecursor.close();
            pd.dismiss();

        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }
```

Add_Image.Xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_images_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:minWidth="110px"
        android:text="Back To Main" android:onClick="onClick" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_images_selected"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_images_back"
        android:text="Select" android:onClick="onClick"/>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/Add_Select_PhoneImageGrid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/btn_images_selected"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

add_view_galleryitem.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/add_view_thumbImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/add_view_itemCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post the stacktrace. are you updating ui from the the thread? `imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);`. you will get exception.

Comment: @Raghunandan That seems to be the case indeed: `new Thread(add_images.this)` in his `onCreate`.

Comment: use `runonUiThread` to update ui or else you will get called from wrong thread exception only the original thread ....

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
    pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    pd.setMessage("Please Wait...");
    pd.setIndeterminate(false);
    pd.setCancelable(true);
    pd.show();
new Thread(add_images.this) {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                           try {
                                 // code runs in a thread
                                 activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                               // code runs in a UI(main) thread
                                        }
                                 });
                           } catch (final Exception ex) {
                           }
                    }
             }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd really help if you posted the stack trace at the time of the crash. It should be shown as an error in `logcat`.

Anyhow, by the looks of it, you are trying to update the GUI from a separate thread which is **not allowed** by Android (as well as many other GUI frameworks). You can only update the GUI from the GUI thread.

An easy solution would be to just call [`runOnUiThread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29), but the Android SDK has much better solutions for asynchronously loading data and updating the GUI afterwards. For example, a [`Loader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html) loads its data in a separate thread and posts the results to a `LoaderCallbacks` implementation *in the GUI thread*. Furthermore, the `LoaderManager` takes care of recovering a previous instance `Loader` when your activity is restarted after a configuration change (e.g. the device is rotated) and/or creating a new `Loader` and querying it.

For the specific case of loading data from a `ContentResolver`, such as from the MediaStore, you can use a [`CursorLoader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html).

The [Android guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) have an *excellent* explanation of how loaders work and how you can use them. There are also sample projects in the SDK, for example the `LoaderCursor` sample project.